# htaccess file exclude bots but allow them to access robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to use htaccess to block specific user agents but allow them to see robots.txt
I thought the following would work but they still get the 308 error for robots.txt
Any ideas folks?

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot1 [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot2 [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot3 [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/)?robots\.txt
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$1 [R=308,L]
```

I also need to exclude some agents from accessing the ALL files including the robots.txt file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} agent1 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} agent2 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} agent3 [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: The code you posted should work. But note that a 308 is “permanent” so gets cached persistently by the browser. If you have only recently changed the rule to exclude “robots.txt” then it could be a caching issue. But also consider sending a 403 instead (as in @Nitesh’s answer) instead of redirecting (back to the client). Aside: There’s no need to make the slash prefix optional or enclose it in parentheses.

Comment: Thank you. The 308 is there for another reason but will remove the slash prefix to simplify the code.
Also just amended the original question as some agents do need to be completely blocked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block specific user agents but allow them to access **robots.txt** , you should consider using the F flag for forbidden instead. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Allow access to robots.txt for all user agents
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ - [L]

# Block specific user agents
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot1 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot2 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Hmm that could be close to what would work.
However I also need to block some other user agents from accessing robots.txt

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} admantx.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Go-http-client [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} python [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the above and my amended question, would this work?

```
RewriteEngine On

# ban certain user agents from access to entire site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} agent1 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} agent2 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} agent3 [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

# Allow access to robots.txt for all user agents
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ - [L]

# Block specific user agents
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot1 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot2 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```